# Can a Java @Statless EJB with @RolesAllowed inherit methods from a class without security annotations?

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb, jaas

I have a Java EE project in Eclipse Neon with facets Java 1.8, JSF 2.2, JPA 2.1, deploying on WildFly 10.0. I'm using security annotations as below:

```
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed("SysAdmin")
public class EJBImpl extends POJOSuperClass implements EJBInterface {
    /* ... */
}
```

The thing is: `POJOSuperClass` does not use security annotations:

```
public abstract class POJOSuperClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        /* ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

When the JSF bean calls the inherited `someMethod()` on an instance of `EJBImpl`, I get an exception, even if logged in as a user that has the role `SysAdmin`:

```
ERROR ... EJB Invocation failed on component EJBImpl for method public abstract void POJOSuperClass.someMethod(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public abstract void POJOSuperClass.someMethod() of bean: EJBImpl is not allowed
```

If I add the `@PermitAll` annotation to `POJOSuperClass`, it works as I want (no exceptions if logged in as admin, exception if not), but I want to keep the POJOSuperClass, which is a class I reuse in different projects, free of such annotations (if I'm not mistaken, if I use the annotations on the superclass, I have to use it also in the subclasses, an imposition I don't want to have in other projects that do not use JAAS).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you remove `@RolesAllowed("SysAdmin")` from the class  and put it only on the methods to be accessed by `SysAdmin`?

Comment: The problem is that `EJBImpl` inherits the methods to be accessed by `SysAdmin` from `POJOSuperClass` and I don't want to have any annotations in the superclass...

Answer (score 1):

Refering to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2988

> Basically class level annotations only apply to methods defined by the class, not to methods defined by the super class. The term 'all applicable business methods of the class' just means the methods that are declared on the class itself, not on any superclass

You will have to delegate all methods explicitely, i.e. that you do not call any inherited method of `POJOSuperClass` on `EJBImpl` directly but rather use `EJBImpl` as "entry point" facade and `POJOSuperClass` as kind of "static utility class".

Another possibility would be to invert the security mechanism, i.e. a missing method permission would deny access at the moment which can be flipped by extending your `jboss-ejb3.xml` similar to

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
               version="3.1"
               xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
               impl-version="2.0">

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>false</s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```